# thor websocket load testing - add custom http header in web socket handshake request

Tags: python, websocket, load-testing, stress-testing, thor

I am using [thor](https://github.com/observing/thor) for load testing my twisted based autobahn websocket server. For authentication purposes my websocket application need a custom http header (Authorization : Bearer token) in websocket handshake request as part of authentication. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like thor supports adding headers so you either need to patch it to add this support or consider another tool like:

- [Gatling](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/http/websocket.html)
- [Apache JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri. I did the patch as the underlying ws node library which is used by thor support this feature.